# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable on streamlit site

Tags: python, streamlit

so, i want to implement some math formula to my streamlit app, for my project. but there is an error like this:

```
import streamlit as st

st.title("PERSAMAAN FUNGSI KUADRAT")
st.header("DISKRIMINAN (b² -4 a c)")
db = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai b")
da = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai a")
dc = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai c")
dd = db*db(-4*da*dc)
st.subheader(dd)
```

it said TypeError: `'float' object is not callable`. Any idea?

Comment: `db(...)` is interpreted as a function call. Did you mean `db*(...)` for multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import streamlit as st

st.title("PERSAMAAN FUNGSI KUADRAT")
st.header("DISKRIMINAN (b² -4 a c)")

db = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai b", value=0)
da = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai a", value=0)
dc = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai c", value=0)

dd = db * db - (4 * (da * dc))  # Correction
st.subheader(dd)
```

output:
[image]